# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class com.mysql.jdbc.Statement, but interface was expected

Tags: mysql, sql, database

when this exception come for SQL

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class com.mysql.jdbc.Statement, but interface was expected
```

Can you please explain ? does it come due to mysql jar changes to next version ?

Comment: Please post the code to the class that produces this Exception. Specifically, I am interested in seeing all the `import` statements at the top of the file.

Comment: I get clue from that I had added wrong statement class from old Jar 
I need to remove old jar :)

Answer (score 1):

In mysql-connecter-java-5.0 Statement is a class. in 5.1, it's an interface.

The code you write shouldn't care too much. But if you compile against the new version, then run against the old version, you'll have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile your code wih mysql-connector-java-5.0 and you are using mysql-connector-java-5.1 at time of code execution then you will have this issue.

If you are java developer then you can reproduce this issue easily.
In import statement use "import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement" write some jdbc logic,compile your code against "mysql-connector-java-5.0.jar" and  at time of class execution use "mysql-connector-java-5.1.jar".

To resolve this issue verify if the version used for compilation and execution is same.