# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /home/index.jsp at line 54

Tags: java, jsp

I am having trouble with this exception:

```
type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /home/index.jsp at line 54

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this   request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /home/index.jsp at line 54

51:     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.png"> 
52:     <style type="text/css"> 
53:     <%  
54:         HashMap<String,Object> background = com.controlj.green.definitions.Utilities.getBackground();
55:             String background_image = "";
56:             if(!background.isEmpty()){
57:                 background_image = "data:image/png;base64," + background.get("bytes").toString();


Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
com.controlj.green.servlets.Index.doGet(Index.java:51)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class   com.mysql.jdbc.Statement, but interface was expected
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
 org.apache.jsp.home.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:83)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 com.controlj.green.servlets.Index.doGet(Index.java:51)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

 root cause

 java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class com.mysql.jdbc.Statement, but interface was expected
 com.controlj.green.definitions.Utilities.getBackground(Utilities.java:172)    org.apache.jsp.home.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:68)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 com.controlj.green.servlets.Index.doGet(Index.java:51)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

 note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 logs.
 Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
```

I really don't know what's wrong in line 54.

It is apparently calling this :
com.controlj.green.definitions.Utilities.getBackground();

which is :

```
    import java.util.*;

    public static HashMap<String,Object> getBackground() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    if(establishConnection()){

        Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("select bytes from connection_string");

        ResultSetMetaData md = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = md.getColumnCount();
        HashMap<String,Object> list = new HashMap<String,Object>();

        if (rs.next()) {
            for(int i=1; i<=columns; ++i){
                list.put(md.getColumnName(i),rs.getObject(i));
                }
            }    
        return list;
    }else{
        return null;
    }

}
```

What could be wrong in this?

Thanks.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027104/java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-found-class-com-mysql-jdbc-statement-bu) maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1):

From the stacktrace,

> root cause javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Statement, but interface was expected

Why have you cast the `statement` class here ,

```
Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
```

it needs to be,

```
Statement st =con.createStatement();
```

Expecting `con` to be connection object

**Update:**

As per the error you have shared its the wrong imports ,

Wrong classes

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
```

should be

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi san krish,
When I removed the casting (Statement), a notice is raised:
        Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.sql.Statement to com.mysql.jdbc.Statement

Comment: Updated my answer. check the import and let me know for any issues

Comment: Here are my imports:
        `import java.sql.Connection;`  
        `import java.sql.DriverManager;`  
       `import java.sql.PreparedStatement;`  
        `import java.sql.ResultSet;`  
        `import java.sql.SQLException;`  
        `import com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData;`  
       `import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;`  

So which one to remove or use?

Answer (score 0):

What is con in
`Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();`
Where does is come from. And anyway you donot need a cast to Statement.

Comment: Hi Darshan Lila,
con is coming from another Class's public property:
 public static Connection con;
FYI

Comment: The Statement call should come from java.sql pakage. Check your imports.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think we need casting as you did here

`Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();`

as long as `con` is an object of type `java.sql.Connection`

or may be you are using some older version of `mysql-connector.jar` trying replacing it with some [newer version](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6) and import the connection statements again

Comment: I would say "as long as `st` is an object of type `java.sql.Statement`". Likely the OP is casting due to importing the wrong `Statement`

Comment: thats most likely to be the reason here *wrong import*

Comment: Hi M.Sharma,
I am using mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar 
FYI

Comment: Did u try reimporting the statements from java.sql package?

Answer (score 0):

From where are you getting the connection?. Global variable?, I would try to changes your prepared statement for something like this. I dont know if you´re controlling the exception in some point to close the connection by the way.

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;

try{
    ps = conn.prepareStatement("select bytes from connection_string");
    ps.executeQuery();
} catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("");
} finally {
   try{
       if(ps!=null){
           ps.close();
       }
       if(conn!=null){
           conn.close();
       }
   } catch(Exception ex){
       System.out.println("");
   }
}
```

Comment: I really didn't understand what this code got to do with the OP's problem

Comment: looking the stacktrace, his problem is when he is creating the Statement         Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
I believe that it´s worth it to try another to create the PrepareStatement instead to retrieve the interface Statement